# Dataflow hangs with steps in running - no elements created/output. Works with Direct Runner

Tags: python-3.x, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm writing a Beam pipeline to run some arbitrary Pandas code on a collection of CSVs. This needs to run using a later version of Pandas('0.24.2') than the version that ships on Dataflow, and out of convenience I'm running this on Python 3.6, instead of 3.5.

This works when running using the Direct Runner, but does not work when running on DataFlow.

Here's a sample of the pipeline:

https://gist.github.com/mayansalama/b5756493f478a99224cd5c51ca4304e9

I can run this with the direct runner with no issues:

```
python pipeline.py --infile-pattern gs://[test_bucket]/csv_tests/ --output-table [PROJECT]:[DATASET].[TABLE_NAME]
```

When I try to run this on Dataflow this job hangs, scaling up but not actually doing anything. Originally I got the error:

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'PandifyCSV' on <module 'dataflow_worker.start' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dataflow_worker/start.py'>
```

However with save_main_session this is no longer an issue:

```
python pipeline.py --infile-pattern  gs://[test_bucket]/csv_tests/ \
                    --output-table [PROJECT]:[DATASET].[TABLE_NAME]  \
                    --requirements_file requirements.txt \
                    --runner DataflowRunner \
                    --project im-dev-219022  \
                    --temp_location gs://test_bucket_im_dev/tmp/ \
                    --experiment ignore_py3_minor_version \
                    --save_main_session
```

I'll try running on py3.5 later tonight, without the ignore_py3_minor_version option.

Any ideas in the meantime?

EDIT: I got this working, this issue was passing pandas via the `--requirements_file`. Doing a `pip download pandas==0.24.2` and passing that using the `--extra_package` argument solved this problem.

Comment: Do you really need to install pandas? According to [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/sdk-worker-dependencies#beam-2x-python) it is pre-installed to Dataflow.

Comment: Is your pipeline sample complete? Often `AttributeError` in `dataflow_worker.start` is called by [BEAM-6158](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-6158): when `super()` is called inside the classes methods. But I don't see any calls to `super()` in your pipeline so maybe you have removed it before publishing the Gist?